# Trying to make a custom shortcut keyboard with esp32 with arduino ide

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Ok, so as in the title I am trying to make a custom shortcut keyboard with esp32 with Arduino ide and keep running into errors so if someone could fix it all for me that would be appreciated.

one of these errors is: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]

Code:

```
#include <BleKeyboard.h>

BleKeyboard bleKeyboard;

const int buttonPin[] = {36, 39, 34, 35, 32, 33};
int pinCount = 6;

int potPin = 2;
int prevPotState = -1;
int potState = -1;
int potTolerance = 1;
long potDebounceDelay = 20;

int buttonState[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
int prevButtonState[] = {HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH};
long startedPressing[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
boolean longPressing[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false};

long lastDebounceTime[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // 1 more for the pot

long debounceDelay = 0;

boolean testHardware = false;

int keyComb(char key1 = 0, char key2 = 0, char key3 = 0, char key4 = 0) {
  if (key1 != 0) {
    bleKeyboard.press(key1);
  }
  if (key2 != 0) {
    bleKeyboard.press(key2);
  }
  if (key3 != 0) {
    bleKeyboard.press(key3);
  }
  if (key4 != 0) {
    bleKeyboard.press(key4);
  }
  delay(100);
  bleKeyboard.releaseAll();
}

int sendLine(char const * line) {
  bleKeyboard.print(line);
  delay(750);
  keyComb(KEY_RETURN);
}

// Output actions. Probably the only part that you need to change
int outputAction(int currentButton, int typeOfPress = 0) {
  // typeOfPress 1: on push; 2: on release; 3: on long press; 4: on lingering press.
  // actions on release, on long press and lingering press include the action press. Action lingering press cancels action release and long press.

  if (testHardware) {
    bleKeyboard.print(currentButton + 1);
    if (typeOfPress == 1) {
      bleKeyboard.print(" pressed ");
    }
    if (typeOfPress == 2) {
      bleKeyboard.print(" released ");
    }
    if (typeOfPress == 3) {
      bleKeyboard.print(" long ");
    }
    if (typeOfPress == 4) {
      bleKeyboard.print(" lingering ");
    }
    bleKeyboard.print(millis());
    bleKeyboard.print("Pressed: ");
    bleKeyboard.print(lastDebounceTime[currentButton]);
    keyComb(KEY_RETURN);
  } else {

    if (currentButton + 1 == 1) {
      if (typeOfPress == 1) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'M');
      }
      if (typeOfPress == 3) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'S');
      }
    }
    if (currentButton + 1 == 2) {
      if (typeOfPress == 1) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'P');
      }
    }
    if (currentButton + 1 == 3) {
      if (typeOfPress == 1) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'M');
      }
    }
    if (currentButton + 1 == 4) {
      if (typeOfPress == 2) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'L');
      }
    }
    if (currentButton + 1 == 5) {
      if (typeOfPress == 1) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'K');
      }
    }
    if (currentButton + 1 == 6) {
      if (typeOfPress == 1) {
        keyComb(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, KEY_LEFT_ALT, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, 'N');
      }
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  for (int thisPin = pinCount - 1; thisPin >= 0; thisPin--) {
    pinMode(buttonPin[thisPin], INPUT);
    analogWrite(buttonPin[thisPin], HIGH); // In some versions use INPUT_PULLUP to use the built-in pull up resistor
  }
  bleKeyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  for (int thisPin = pinCount - 1; thisPin >= 0; thisPin--) {
    buttonState[thisPin] = analogRead(buttonPin[thisPin]);
    // HIGH = state 1 <- button not pressed
    // LOW  = state 0 <- button pressed

    // On longer press
    if ((startedPressing[thisPin] == 0) || ((millis() - startedPressing[thisPin]) <= 1200)) {

      // Debouncing not working properly with current hardware
      //if (((buttonState[thisPin] != prevButtonState[thisPin])) && ((millis() - lastDebounceTime[thisPin]) > debounceDelay)) {
      if ((buttonState[thisPin] != prevButtonState[thisPin])) {

        if (buttonState[thisPin] == 0) {
          // Standard press action
          startedPressing[thisPin] = millis();
          outputAction(thisPin, 1);
        } else {

          if (!longPressing[thisPin]) {
            if ((millis() - startedPressing[thisPin]) < 500) {
              // On release (to avoid standard action if is incompatible with Long or Longer action)
              outputAction(thisPin, 2);
            } else {
              // Long action (+standard action already sent)
              outputAction(thisPin, 3);
            }
          }

          startedPressing[thisPin] = 0;
          longPressing[thisPin] = false;
        }
        lastDebounceTime[thisPin] = millis();
      }
    } else {
      outputAction(thisPin, 4);

      longPressing[thisPin] = true;
      startedPressing[thisPin] = 0;
    }

    prevButtonState[thisPin] = buttonState[thisPin];
  }
  // The pot
  int thisPin = pinCount; // To consider it the last one in the lastDebounceTime array
  potState = (int) (analogRead(potPin) / 6);
  if (prevPotState == -1) {
    prevPotState = potState;
  }
  if (((potState > prevPotState + potTolerance) || (potState < prevPotState - potTolerance))
      && ((millis() - lastDebounceTime[thisPin]) > potDebounceDelay)
     ) {

    if (potState > prevPotState) {
      keyComb(KEY_UP_ARROW);
    } else {
      keyComb(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
    }
    lastDebounceTime[thisPin] = millis();
    prevPotState = potState;
  }
}
```

!!!FILLER!!!
hehehuheuheuheuhuehdkl;lbkljdfklbfklvjnbgkljnjbgvnjkvjbkvfnvkljklbjk

Comment: Isn't the error message self explanatory? Several of your functions are defined to return an `int` value but they don't return anything. There is not a single `return` statement in all that code.

Comment: Please spend some effort to fix your code by debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

From the declaration of your function, you declare the function can return an integer in the code. But you don't return an integer.

For your example,

```
int sendLine(char const * line) {
  bleKeyboard.print(line);
  delay(750);
  keyComb(KEY_RETURN);
}
```

You don't return an integer in the function sendLine.

Another function you declared to have the same issue too.